# Getting an error when trying to find a local image with helm/docker

Tags: docker, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, docker-registry

I have a local kubernetes cluster (minikube), that is trying to load images from my local Docker repo.

When I do a "docker images", I get:

```
cluster.local/container-images/app-shiny-app-validation-app-converter            1.6.9
cluster.local/container-images/app-shiny-app-validation                          1.6.9
```

Given I know the above images are there, I run some helm commands which uses these images, but I get the below error:

```
Events:
  Type     Reason     Age                  From               Message
  ----     ------     ----                 ----               -------
  Normal   BackOff    66s (x2 over 2m12s)  kubelet            Back-off pulling image "cluster.local/container-images/app-shiny-app-validation-app-converter:1.6.9"
  Warning  Failed     66s (x2 over 2m12s)  kubelet            Error: ImagePullBackOff
  Normal   Pulling    51s (x3 over 3m24s)  kubelet            Pulling image "cluster.local/container-images/app-shiny-app-validation-app-converter:1.6.9"
  Warning  Failed     11s (x3 over 2m13s)  kubelet            Failed to pull image "cluster.local/container-images/app-shiny-app-validation-app-converter:1.6.9": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Error response from daemon: Get https://cluster.local/v2/: dial tcp: lookup cluster.local: Temporary failure in name resolution
  Warning  Failed     11s (x3 over 2m13s)  kubelet            Error: ErrImagePull
```

Anyone know how I can fix this? Seems the biggest problem is `Get https://cluster.local/v2/: dial tcp: lookup cluster.local: Temporary failure in name resolution`

Comment: What is the actual Kubernetes system (minikube, kind, Docker Desktop)?  Do your local images in fact have the `...:1.6.9` tag?

Comment: @DavidMaze I am using minikube locally

Comment: @DavidMaze and yes local images do have the proper tag

Comment: Do you need to [build your image within the minikube environment](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/pushing/); have you run `eval $(minikube docker-env)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since minikube is being used, you can refer to their documentation.
It is recommended that if a `imagePullPolicy` is being used, it needs to be set to `Never`. If set to `Always`, it will try to reach out and pull from the network.

From docs: https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/pushing/
"Tip 1: Remember to turn off the imagePullPolicy:Always (use imagePullPolicy:IfNotPresent or imagePullPolicy:Never) in your yaml file. Otherwise Kubernetes won’t use your locally build image and it will pull from the network."

Answer (score 2):

1. Add `cluster.local` to your `/etc/hosts` file in all your kubernetes nodes.

```
192.168.12.34 cluster.local
```

2. Check whether you can login to registry using `docker login cluster.local`
3. If your registry has self-signed certificates, copy `cluster.local.crt` key to all kubernetes worker nodes `/etc/docker/certs.d/cluster.local/ca.crt`

Comment: What IP does that refer to? I tried putting that in but didn't get me any closer

Comment: @MikeK. IP address of your registry server.